# orgnlList: for (Integer number : numbers) What does this stand for?

Tags: java

I was reading a book and found the below code :

```
orgnlList: for (Integer number : numbers)
```

orgnlList is not a variable. So please explain what does it stand for?

Answer (score 2):

It is a label for a break statement.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Basically, using the instruction "break orgnlList;" will exit this loop.